# Bash not finding file

Tags: bash, file-access, debian-stretch

I'm running Debian 9 as VM from serial console on Azure.

Link to sample input file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aIIjWO70clU8u4_gV2X_8c17HmEnqjr_

I was given some code from the help people at antiSMASH. It should iterate through genbank files in a folder and process them with the antiSMASH package:

```
for infile in inputs/*.gbk; do
    antismash $infile --taxon fungi --input-type nucl --knownclusterblast
done
```

I tried running it while at the directory containing the files, and I tried running it while at the directory containing the folder "inputs" which contains the .gb files:

```
(antismash) macpat@Debian9:~/inputs$ for infile in inputs/*.gb; do
> antismash $infile --taxon fungi --input-type nucl --knownclusterblast
> done
ERROR   25/05 21:53:00   No sequence file found at 'inputs/*.gb'
```

I ran this:

```
(antismash) macpat@Debian9:~$ for infile in ~/inputs/*.gb; do echo $infile; done
/home/macpat/inputs/DQ660910.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/EU872212.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/GU930713.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/GU930714.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/HM180407.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/HM180409.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/HQ823618.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/HQ823619.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/HQ823620.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/HQ823621.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/JN408682.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/JQ340775.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/JX067626.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/JX067627.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/JX232185.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/JX232186.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/JX232187.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/JX232188.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/KJ501919.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777489.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777490.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777491.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777492.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777493.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777494.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777495.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777496.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777497.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777498.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777499.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777500.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777501.gb
/home/macpat/inputs/MG777502.gb
```

This is the email I was sent by the antiSMASH people:

> Dear antiSMASH user,
>
> For running antiSMASH on many input files, I usually write a loop in
>   bash, like so:
>
> ```
> for infile in inputs/*.gbk; do
>     antismash $infile --your --other-options --here done
> ```
>
> Assuming your input files are in GenBank format and located in a
>   subdirectory of your current directory called "input", antiSMASH will
>   run on all your input files sequentially. I'm aware you asked for "all
>   at once", but as antiSMASH has pretty decent CPU and memory
>   requirements, especially when running ClusterBlast, I would not
>   recommend that.
>
> Best regards, Kai

Comment: It looks like you're already in directory `inputs`, so instead of `inputs/*.gbk`, you have to use the relative path `./*.gbk`. Also, you should quote `"$infile"` so blanks and glob characters in filenames have no effect.

Comment: You also seem to mix up `.gb` and `.gbk`, make sure to use the correct one.

Comment: You could reproduce the problem with `ls inputs/*.gb`, so antiSMASH and your os/platform are irrelevant.

Comment: I tried from one directory above inputs as well. And I tried with .gbk, then tried .gb.I haven't tried the quotes on "$infile", I'll give that a go.

Comment: wjandrea, are you saying replacing for infile in with just ls would be synonymous?

Comment: Just ran this: (antismash) macpat@Debian9:~$ for infile in inputs/*.gbk; do
> antismash "$infile" --taxon fungi --input-type nucl --knownclusterblast
> done
ERROR   25/05 22:49:59   No sequence file found at 'inputs/*.gbk'

Comment: Just edited post to add a link to files that I'm attempting to input.

Answer (score 1):

In the failed case you wrote `inputs/*.gb`. In the working one with echo you wrote `~/inputs/*.gb`.

Answer (score 0):

`inputs/` is a relative path, which means you have to be in its parent directory, `/home/macpat`, for it to work. To move to `/home/macpat`, you could run `cd`.

```
cd
for infile in inputs/*.gb; do ...
```

On the other hand, `~/inputs/` is an absolute path, which means it will work from anywhere.

```
for infile in ~/inputs/*.gb; do ...
```

Or if you're want to run the script from within `~/inputs/`, you can run this:

```
cd ~/inputs
for infile in *.gb; do ...
```